# Rally webservice - authentication

Tags: web-services, rally

Does Rally provides any webservice to authenticate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use basic auth and query against our standard WSAPI.

[Here](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/blame/702c2cd4bcfe0c6abc665736d58cfed376e84616/src/com/rallydev/rest/RallyRestApi.java#L78) is an example of our Java Rest Api authenticating in GitHub.