# How do I connect to Rally from Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, rally

I'm trying to add Rally functionality to Google Apps Sheets using the Google App Script engine. Everything seems fairly simple, except managing the authentication from a user on the Google Apps system trying to connect with Rally. Google's UrlFetchApp.fetch() function seems to do the trick, except for the Auth bit. Any suggestions?

```
function RallyQuery(sz, order, fetch, stylesheet)
{
  if (typeof fetch === "undefined"){ fetch = true; }
  if (typeof stylesheet === "undefined"){ stylesheet = "/slm/doc/webservice/browser.xslsz";}

  var result = "[null]";
  var query  = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.42/task?query=" + sz 
             + "&order=" + order 
             + "&fetch=" + fetch 
             + "&stylesheet=" + stylesheet;

  result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(query);

  return result;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "seems to do the trick"? Can you site a specific error or problem you are having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404213/rally-webservice-authentication), the rally webservice uses basic authentication. You should check the [web services documentation](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) to validate that. (I'm not a registered user, so I can't.)

Here's how your `RallyQuery` could be refactored to include basic authentication:

```
function RallyQuery(sz, order, fetch, stylesheet)
{
  if (typeof fetch === "undefined"){ fetch = true; }
  if (typeof stylesheet === "undefined"){ stylesheet = "/slm/doc/webservice/browser.xslsz";}

  var username = "USERNAME";
  var password = "PASSWORD";

  var result = "[null]";
  var url = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.42/task"
  var options = {
      "query" : sz, 
      "order" : order, 
      "fetch" : fetch, 
      "stylesheet" : stylesheet,
      "headers": {
          "Authorization": "Basic "
              + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password)
                 }
    }
  result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);

  return result;
}
```

Alternatively, you may need to look into a [LoginKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246913/login-to-rally-using-app-sdk).

Comment: Mogsdad - That works great. Thanks! As for the LoginKey, Rally is updating their API and the 2.0 version doesn't (yet) support keys, but will someday soon. So while it's not of use to me, anybody finding this in a few months time may want to look into that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, for external javascript Rally Apps, you will need to use a [LoginKey](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/loginkey). This key must be tied to a read only (viewer) account (i.e. the account cannot have editor privileges). There are some security issues with this approach however (as noted at the link).